# Encrypting DB passwords in node.js

Tags: node.js, passwords

In my application I use a config file to store the database connection details. How can I use an encrypted password and later decrypt it while making a connection ?

```
config.mongodb =  {
    connectionString: '',
    server: 'localhost',
    database:'db',
    user:'user',
    password:'password'
};
```

Comment: If someone were to obtain access to that file, wouldn't they also have access to the code that decrypts it?

Comment: In other words, there's no point in encrypting it here.

Comment: However you were planning to protect the decryption password, just protect the database password that way instead, and you won't need to bother with encrypting it.

Comment: [#2 on How NOT to Store Passwords! - Computerphile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q)